# Estimating $R^2$ when some coefficients are forced (i.e., restricted coefficients)

Tags: r, regression, mathematical-statistics

I am running a regression in R, and wanted to find the right way to calculate the $R^2$. I have an identity that I am empirically testing with data that is y = x1 - x2 + x3 (unfortunately dont have an MLE) First, I do:

```
y ~ lm(y ~ x1 + x2 + x3, data=data1)
```

I get the coefficients for x1, x2, and x3 as 1,-1, and 1, and the R^2 as 1.

In the next step, I have to force coefficients of both x1, and x2 to 1, and -1 respectively. I use https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8234972/how-to-set-the-coefficient-value-in-regression-r

```
y ~ lm(y ~ offset(x1) + offset(-1*x2)), data=data1)
```

Note I have omitted x3 in this model, and then have only the constant term. But I get the $R^2$ to be 0.00. I expected the $R^2$ to drop, but not to zero. I believe the constant term should capture/explain some of the variation. So, I think I may not be correctly capturing the $R^2$ for the second model, and have to manually calculate the $R^2$? Any idea on how to calculate/derive the $R^2$ when using offset?

Comment: Did you read the note in `?lm` that says: "Offsets specified by offset will not be included in predictions by predict.lm, whereas those specified by an offset term in the formula will be."

Comment: I might be wrong but I cannot thing of any example that would give coefficients of 1,-1,1. That would mean that all of your variables are multiples of y in which case you would get 1 for the first coefficient and NA for the others. Is this why you say the test was empirical? Did you run the models separately maybe i.e. one for each variable?

Comment: It's really the R^2 of 1 (rather than a coefficient of 1 or -1) that suggests a perfect fit of one or more the the variables to the response.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "the constant term should capture/explain some of the variation".  How can a constant value "explain" variation at all?  (I think this is why you are getting an r squared of 0 - you have no actually varying explanatory variables, so you can't attribute any of the variation in your dependent variable to your explanatory variables).

Comment: @Dwin - Thank you for pointing out. I looked it further... So is the issue that I have multiple offsets?  So the way I have offset(x1) -- it is included in the predictions then correct?

Comment: You start out and obtain a perfect fit with the desired coefficients. Why, then, do you want to proceed with a constrained regression?  There seems to be no point.

Comment: @whuber note that I have omitted x3 from the model in the second regression. So I am basically trying to see how much of the variation is captured by the constant term i.e., the intercept term, that absorbs the omitted variable x3.  Don-Dresser- LatentView -- I meant the intercept term. The reason I run this set up is as I have another proxy for x3, that I intend to use in the next step.

Comment: OK, I see. But I don't understand why you're messing around with "offsets": if you want to force the coefficients to be $1$ and $-1$, then all you have to do is change $y$ to $y-x_1+x_2$ and drop $x_1$ and $x_2$ altogether, as in `fit <- lm(y-x1+x2 ~ 1, data=data1)` (and that, in turn is just as easily fit by computing `mean(y-x1+x2)`). You don't supply enough information to explain why you get an $R^2$ of $0$--there are no data or reproducible code to work with here.

Comment: I'm going to be Mr. Pedantic here.  You shouldn't say "estimating $R^2$'.  $R^2$ is a measure of fit, it's a statistic based on your data, it is not a population parameter.  You should say 'calculate $R^2$'.

Comment: @Alaska On the contrary, $R^2$ is a property of the model.  It's not really a measure of fit, either!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like manually calculating the R^2 might be the easiest solution.

```
> set.seed(0)
> 
> n <- 100
> x1 <- rnorm(n)
> x2 <- rnorm(n)
> x3 <- rnorm(n)
> y <- x1 - x2 + x3
> 
> df <- data.frame(y=y, x1=x1, x2=x2, x3=x3)
> 
> unconstrained <- lm(y ~ x1 + x2 + x3, data=df)
> summary(unconstrained)

Call:
lm(formula = y ~ x1 + x2 + x3, data = df)

Residuals:
       Min         1Q     Median         3Q        Max 
-1.651e-15 -3.019e-16 -1.195e-16  4.760e-17  8.542e-15 

Coefficients:
              Estimate Std. Error    t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) -6.661e-17  1.010e-16 -6.590e-01    0.511    
x1           1.000e+00  1.158e-16  8.634e+15   <2e-16 ***
x2          -1.000e+00  1.057e-16 -9.464e+15   <2e-16 ***
x3           1.000e+00  9.638e-17  1.038e+16   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1

Residual standard error: 1.007e-15 on 96 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:      1, Adjusted R-squared:      1 
F-statistic: 8.926e+31 on 3 and 96 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16

Warning message:
In summary.lm(unconstrained) :
  essentially perfect fit: summary may be unreliable
> 
> constrained <- lm(y ~ offset(x1) + offset(-1*x2), data=df)
> summary(constrained)

Call:
lm(formula = y ~ offset(x1) + offset(-1 * x2), data = df)

Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-2.97212 -0.68379 -0.01416  0.58460  2.43989 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)  0.06722    0.10521   0.639    0.524

Residual standard error: 1.052 on 99 degrees of freedom

> 
> # http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_determination
> yhat <- predict(constrained)
> ss_tot <- sum((y - mean(y))^2)
> ss_res <- sum((y - yhat)^2)
> r2 <- 1 - ss_res / ss_tot
> r2
[1] 0.5961833
```